# How to explode user id from a database column?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table name messages. There is a column name `receiver_id` I need to fetch record where **receiver_id = 4** but i am always getting null output.

See my table Screenshot-

[image]

Above screenshot there are 3rows. second and third rows exist `4` along with other ids i need to explode that and show the second and third record.

How to write MySQL query?

Comment: Do not store data as comma separated string. For your issue checkout find_in_set function in mysql.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty This find_in_set() not working in CakePHP i am getting `Error: Call to undefined function find_in_set()` how to fix that issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Storing comma separated values is really a bad design you should **[`normalize`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)** it first by storing all association of receiver in a junction table,If you are not able to alter your schema  then for your current situation you can use [`find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to search values in a comma separated list

```
select * from table 
where find_in_set(4,receiver_id ) >0
```

Comment: I would gladly upvote a second time for the sound advice *Storing comma separated values is really a bad design*.

Comment: In this case receiver 44 will return also positive for `find_in_set(4,receiver_id)` :(

Comment: This find_in_set() not working in CakePHP i am getting `Error: Call to undefined function find_in_set()
File: E:\xampp\htdocs\2014\profect\app\Controller\MessagesController.php
Line: 24` how to fix that issue?

Comment: @learnphp php this new question related to php so better to ask new one with the tag for cake php also `find_in_set` is Mysql's function not php's

Answer (score 2):

This should also work ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58e4f/5/0)):

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages
WHERE receiver_id LIKE '%,4,%'
   OR receiver_id LIKE '4,%'
   OR receiver_id LIKE '%,4'
   OR receiver_id = '4'
```

Or with regex ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58e4f/8/0)):

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages
WHERE receiver_id REGEXP '4,|,4,|,4'
   OR receiver_id = '4'
```

Comment: youforgot the case `receiver_id=4` - if `4` is the only value in the field, then your query would fail.

Comment: **@Marc B**, fixed the queries, but **M Khalid Junaid** answer is clearly better/simpler.