# How come my query works in phpmyadmin but not in my php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query I'm trying to run in my php code and it is only returning one result, but if i run the same query in phpmyadmin it works. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
 <?php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product_packs` WHERE `name` IN('" . implode("', '", $_SESSION['cart_items']) . "')";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0){
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
             echo     "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2'>
                 <div class='products " . $row['brandName'] . " all " . $row['product_range'] . "' id='products'>
                     <div class='hovereffect'>
                         <img class='img-responsive productimg' src='" . $row['img'] . "' alt=''>
                         <div class='overlay1'>
                             <h2> " . $row['name'] . "</h2>
                             <p> 
                                 " . $row['title'] . "
                             <br>
                             <br>
                                 " . $row['price'] . "
                             <br>
                             <a href='remove_from_cart.php?name=" . $row['name'] . "&price=" . $row['price'] . "'>
                                 Remove From Cart 
                             </a> 
                             </p>
                         </div>  
                     </div>
                 </div>";
         }
?>
```

I have printed the query to make sure the result of the implode is correct and it seems to be as i can run the result in phpmyadmin and it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your `$_SESSION['cart_items'])` contains the same items as the query you send over phpmyadmin. The code looks ok afais.

Comment: may be **$conn** is undefined ... *enable* your errors

Comment: what error is showing ..?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (NOT tested as far as I have not sufficent data provided form you):

**UPDATED:**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product_packs` WHERE `name` IN('" . implode("', '", $_SESSION['cart_items']) . "')";

// dump the query send to the database  
$var_dump($sql);

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){

    $resultset_count = $result->num_rows;
    // dump the number of resultsets in the query
    var_dump($resultset_count);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    echo "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2'>
            <div class='products " . $row['brandName'] . " all " . $row['product_range'] . "' id='products'>
                <div class='hovereffect'>
                <img class='img-responsive productimg' src='" . $row['img'] . "' alt=''>
                <div class='overlay1'>
                    <h2> " . $row['name'] . "</h2>
                    <p> 
                    " . $row['title'] . "
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    " . $row['price'] . "
                    <br>
                    <a href='remove_from_cart.php?name=" . $row['name'] . "&price=" . $row['price'] . "'>Remove From Cart </a> 
                    </p>
                </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: If this does not work please dump(`var_dump($aRows;)`) `$aRows` (or `$row` if you use your old code instead of mine):

Comment: this has returned me with two errors.

Notice: Undefined variable: aRow

&

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: If you share the error message we might help you ;-) did your old code reutrned an error? if yes, which

Comment: Please provide the result you get by sending the sql query in phpmyadmin and the result of a var_dump($row) after adding this in the 3. line of your code: `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();var_dump($row);die;`

Comment: I just did a dump of $aRows and it is showing all the info for one product even though the query is for two products

Comment: original didnt get any errors it was just only displaying one result

Comment: please share the result of the dump

Comment: this is the query printed on the site with two products in it
SELECT * FROM `product_packs` WHERE `name` IN('Rock It Texture', 'Color Obsessed') 
if i run it in phpmyadmin it works fine

Comment: the result of the dump is
array(8) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "3" ["name"]=> string(14) "Color Obsessed" ["header"]=> string(18) "Keep Color Vibrant" ["title"]=> string(20) "Total Confidence To:" ["img"]=> string(39) "pics/products/matrix/color_obsessed.jpg" ["price"]=> string(3) "$75" ["brandName"]=> string(6) "Matrix" ["product_range"]=> string(15) "total_results_1" }

Comment: please dump the content of `$_SESSION['cart_items']`. Your code seems to be working correctly but query only gives you one result. Make a `var_dump($sql);` and compare if the query your code creates is equal to what you send in phpmyadmin

Comment: this is a dump of $sql with two products added to the `$_SESSION['cart_items']`

    `SELECT * FROM 'product_packs' WHERE 'name' IN('Rock It Texture', 'Color Obsessed')`

Comment: That query does bring up the two results in phpmyadmin

Comment: please copy my updated code above and post the result of the two var_dump(); which are included. The error must be somewhere arround the IN('...', '...'). But till now I can't figure out why phpmyadmin is working, and your code not. need some more debug data.

Comment: this is the result of the var_dump

`string(91) "SELECT * FROM 'product_packs' WHERE 'name' IN('first', 'Rock It Texture', 'Color Obsessed')" int(2)`

Comment: You must change the used singel quotation marks used for product_packs and name from ' to `. ( SELECT * FROM \`product_packs\` WHERE \`name\` IN('first', 'Rock It Texture', 'Color Obsessed') )

Comment: oh, sorry i am using ` it was just so it showed up as code text that i changed it to '
the resulting dump is 
( string(91) "SELECT * FROM `product_packs` WHERE `name` IN('first', 'Rock It Texture', 'Color Obsessed')" int(2) )

Comment: So all works as expected till this point... please add a `var_dump($row)` after the line `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){` and share the output

Comment: I cannot post the dump result as it is too long, but I can see from reading it through it has all the data about the two products in the query

Comment: Okay, if both data sets are available in your request the error must be located in your HTML code. Is this project online available somewhere? Do you hide something with your css? have you inspected your HTML code, maybe the elements are hidden?

Comment: thanks for all your help, I went through my HTML and found it was missing a `</div>` tag, I feel so stupid for missing something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `FIND_IN_SET`? It will work for you, I don't know your database structure but I have created an example query that could be of help for you

why don't use FIND_IN_SET? it will work for you i don't know your database structure still i have created query for you it might help you

```
SELECT * FROM product_packs
   WHERE (
      FIND_IN_SET(cart_items, (SELECT cart_items   TABLENAME
          WHERE cart_items = '$_SESSION['cart_items']')
      )
   )
ORDER BY `product_id` ASC
```

Comment: @DrColossos ive tried using `FIND_IN_SET` but it returns a fatal error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function FIND_IN_SET()`

Comment: @J.Stevenson check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977164/how-to-explode-user-id-from-a-database-column/25977216 .it may help you.

Comment: if my understanding after reading that is correct `FIND_IN_SET()` is a sql function but I still don't think i can run the function in php as it returned a fatal error