# Get all row had value in column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How do I get all rows having the value 1, but not 11 in `column news_short`?

Here's my table:

```
id |   news_short  |
 1 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |
 2 | 2,4,5,6,1,5,6 |
 3 | 11,2,5,6,9,4  |
```

Comment: Better normalize your data structure, then it's really simple

Comment: Now you may see why storing key in comma seperated lists in a single column is such a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

I agree you should normalize. But here is the solution the way it sits.

```
Select * from table where news_short like '%1,%' and 
news_short not like '%11,%';
```

Comment: Will also find `91`, `81`, `71` or every other number ending with 1.

Comment: True, will also not eliminate 111, or 1111,  but that is how he asked the question.

Comment: 1 is example, i'had many many number, so i was try find_in_set, it's work for my problem</br>
Thank all guys!

Answer (score 0):

FIND_IN_SET() returns the position of a string if it is present (as a substring) within a list of strings

so you should search if a value is != 11

eg:

```
->where("FIND_IN_SET(news_short) !=", 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be normalize your schema **do not** store relations in form of comma separated list instead create a junction table to maintain a [m:m many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644986/mysql-select-from-comma-separated-string/25645475#25645475) or if its one to many relation between main table and these news_short (probably from other table) values,create a new table as news_short with columns main table id and news(table) id and in each row save one association per your_table and news.

If you aren't able to update/change your schema you could use [`find_in_set()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977164/how-to-explode-user-id-from-a-database-column/25977216#25977216) but its not a good option

```
select * 
from your_table 
where find_in_set(1, news_short) > 0
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb121f/1)